# Symantec Backup Exec 12 not restoring Shared Folders

Tags: symantec

**I am trying to retore shared Folders. They do retore but not with the shared properties.
I have checked the option under general - Restore all files and directories.
Thanks
Vee**

Comment: If Evan's answer is the right answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're saying that "Sharing Permissions" (and, possibly even the fact that the folders were shared) aren't being restored when you restore folders using Backup Exec on a Windows Server machine. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Unless you restore the machine's "System State" (ultimately to restore the registry) you're not going to get the share-related attributes back. The share-related attributes for a folder aren't stored in the filesystem, but rather are stored as registry values in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer\Shares. Restoring the folders won't restore this information into the registry of the server.

Comment: Hi Evan - Yes yo are right I meant to say Sharing Permissions as well as the actual share it self. When I go to shared folders after restoring, only the default shares appear.